# Загрузить jquery библиотеку, выбраную из списка select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как загрузить `jquery` библиотеку выбранной из списка ( `select html` ) ?

Например выбираем `jquery 1.9.0` и тогда загружается библиотека `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` а если выбираем `jquery 2.1.0` тогда загружается библиотека `jquery-2.1.0.min.js` а предыдущая удаляется.

Может какие-то другие варианты загрузки есть.

```
<select onchange="test(this)" id="select_id">
            <option value="0">-Select-</option>
            <option value="jquery-2.1.0.min.js">jquery 2.1.0</option>
            <option value="jquery-1.1.1.min.js">jquery 1.1.1</option>
            <option value="jquery-1.9.0.min.js">jquery 1.9.0</option>
            <option value="jquery-1.8.3.min.js">jquery 1.8.3</option>
            <option value="jquery-1.7.1.min.js">jquery 1.7.1</option>
</select>
```

Js:

```
function test(a) {
   var x = (a.value || a.options[a.selectedIndex].value); 
//alert(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- На jQuery вам потребуется [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)
- На JavaScript это можно сделать так.

Пример:

```
function loadScript(u, c) {
  var d = document, t = 'script',
      o = d.createElement(t),
      s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
  o.src = '//' + u;
  if (c) { o.addEventListener('load', function (e) { c(null, e); }, false); }
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(o, s);
}

// и загрузить скрипт

loadScript('script.js', function() {
    // script ready
});
```

Comment: А можно одну библиотеку удалить, а другую загрузить или для этого нужно, перезагружати страницу и загружать новую библиотеку ?

Comment: @Muson. Так просто не удалить. Но вы можете пойти чуть другим путем. Вы можете перед подключением нового скрипта, освободить переменную $ под новую версию. Вот так: var oldJquery = jQuery.noConflict(); Теперь вы можете смело подключить новую версию через код в ответе и она будет доступна через $. И так далее.
Конечно это довольно громоздко и не рекомендуется. В общем итоге всё равно наверное лучше перезагружать страницу. http://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=61